# MacBook Pro 6,2 12.04 running hot? AHCI

Tags: mac, ahci, bootcamp

I've finally managed to get 12.04 running on my MacBook Pro with a 240GB SSD, I've heard that running an SSD in IDE on Ubuntu can make it run very hot, which I suspsect is what I'm experiencing. Is there any way to enable AHCI?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard or experience this on my Macbook Pro 8,1 15"

What will make it hot though is running it on the non discrete graphic card. 
If you are running the Macbook in bios mode. You dont get to pick which of your two cards to use.

If you run it in EFI mode, your controller will use AHCI mode which is better for your performance  and you can use the builtin intel card which runs cooler.